# Search Stop working after Updating to com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I want to add firebase that's why I update my source code from **com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0** to **11.0.4**

but after I fixed all problems I see that search bar doesn't work when I clicked on button

My App Gradle :

```js
dependencies
        {
            compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
            compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
            compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.3.4@aar'
            compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.1'
            compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
            compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
            compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
            compile 'se.emilsjolander:StickyScrollViewItems:1.1.0'
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

        }


android
        {
            compileSdkVersion 25
            buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
            defaultConfig
                    {
                        minSdkVersion 21
                        targetSdkVersion 22
                        versionName "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}"
                        versionCode 2
                    }
```

My Search XML file :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/global_spacing_l"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/global_keyline_s"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/global_keyline_s"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/search_suggestion_item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Cookbook.Display1" />

</searchable >
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the error? Does it crash? or how?

Comment: No I didn't receive any error, it's work well just the search button doesn't work anymore after updating to ( compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4' )

Answer (score 0):

you have a plugin **"plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'"** in gradle?

```
//end gradle
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Yes, I have     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'